# AWS MySQL RDS DB instance restarted

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, crash

Recently MySQL RDS DB instance restarted twice. All I see is it is switched over to a different node. I searched the logs to see if there was any information that would help me understand why it had stopped working. Following the instance restart, the general, audit, and error logs were all emptied out and started over from scratch.

Would someone kindly tell me how to -

1. Ascertain the cause of its restart? Since it is an automated procedure, I have no knowledge about other nodes.
2. Configure a cloud-watch alarm or notification before it fails over?

Thanks

Comment: You may find this URL to be helpful in finding why your instance was restarted twice.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.MySQL.LogFileSize.html   Not sure what the retention period is for these logs. Search for your reason before too many days expire.  They will roll off AWS storage in two weeks.